# How to use reveal.js as NPM package

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, reveal.js

I'm working on a project and want to include reveal.js slides, but didn't find enough resources for working with it as a dependency.

I first installed reveal.js by `npm install reveal.js`

And in my Slides.js file I did:

```
import Reveal from 'reveal.js';
import Markdown from 'reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.esm.js';

let deck = new Reveal({
   plugins: [ Markdown ]
})
deck.initialize();

export default function Slides() {
  return (
    <>
 
    </>
  )
}
```

as suggested in https://revealjs.com/installation/#installing-from-npm , but I couldn't figure out where to add these html tags

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/reveal.js/dist/reveal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/reveal.js/dist/theme/black.css">
```

And the rest of html tags from https://revealjs.com/markup/ . Do I need to create a new .html file and call it, if so how do I go about the same?

Comment: Link tags should be added to your main html file, e.g. index.html See example here https://github.com/mgramin/percona-community-live-2022